# Difference between shutting down and rebooting PC

Tags: ubuntu, windows-xp, shutdown, reboot

I have windows (XP SP3 32-bit) and linux (Xubuntu TT 64-bit) both installed on my laptop (as a dualboot). Now each of the following behavior has been tested on my PC several times:

- When shutting down / rebooting PC with linux previously loaded and loading linux again, nothing interesting happens.
- When shutting down / rebooting PC with windows previously loaded and loading windows again, nothing interesting happens.
- When shutting down / rebooting PC with windows previously loaded and loading linux, nothing interesting happens.

but

- When rebooting PC with linux previously loaded and loading windows, my USB mouse stops working every time.
- When shutting down PC with linux previously loaded and loading windows, nothing interesting happens.

I actually don't need the help with my mouse, I'd just love to know what's the crazy difference between reboot and shutdown which makes the mouse get stuck. Shutdown and reboot are the same from my point of view.

Comment: I believe that replugging the usb after the reboot will make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The power often doesn't completely go off in a reboot, capacitors will still hold a charge for a few seconds. This could be causing a slight bug in the usb controller or something related.

Comment: This does not explain why the mouse remains working if the reboot was done Windows/Windows or Linux/Linux.

Comment: It does if the device is not disconnecting properly.

Comment: Maybe both OSes perform PCI resets at different time. If Linux does in on startup and Windows does it on shutdown when rebooting (just a hypothesis), you get no PCI reset when rebooting from Linux to Windows. BTW, I wonder if external USB keyboard works in Windows in such scenarios.